# Ajax Request in Sencha Touch working on desktop but not working while deploying on tablet?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a view in Sencha Touch in which I am using external html file using Ajax Request. The code of the view is given below:

```
 Ext.define('Appname.view.Viewname', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'viewname',

initialize : function () {

    this.callParent();

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url     : 'resources/hello.html',
        params  : {
            id : 1
        },
        scope   : this,
        success : function (response) {
            var text = response.responseText;
            this.setHtml(text);
        }
    })
    rotate();
}



});
```

I am trying to load hello.html in my viewname view. When I run the application in my browser, it is working fine. As soon as  I deploy it on my tablet using cordova it doesnot display anything. What is the reason for that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if deploying on android device, check whether on the eclipse project hello.html is present inside the 'assets/www/resources' folder. If not, copy that and then try to create apk for your android device...

Comment: yes.I have checked. hello.html is present in resources folder.